# How can I write this reference in BibteX?

Tags: bibliographies, bibtex

This reference contains a formula and when I write it as follows

```
@article{romeo2011effective,
title={The effective stability parameter for two-component galactic discs: 
is $Q^{- 1}\sim Q^{- 1}_{stars}+ Q^{- 1}_{gas}?$},
author={Romeo, Alessandro B and Wiegert, Joachim},
journal={Monthly Notices of the Royal Astronomical Society},
volume={416},
number={2},
pages={1191--1196},
year={2011},
publisher={The Royal Astronomical Society}
}
```

there are some errors (missing `$` or missing a `{`). Note that I'm using a Persian thesis template (it can be found [here](http://www.parsilatex.com/joomla/index.php/remository/Thesis_Templates/%D8%A7%D8%B3%D8%AA%DB%8C%D9%84-%D9%84%D8%A7%D8%AA%DA%A9-%D8%A8%D8%B1%D8%A7%DB%8C-%D9%BE%D8%A7%DB%8C%D8%A7%D9%86%E2%80%8C%D9%86%D8%A7%D9%85%D9%87%E2%80%8C%D9%87%D8%A7%DB%8C-%DA%A9%D8%A7%D8%B1%D8%B4%D9%86%D8%A7%D8%B3%DB%8C-%D8%AA%D8%A7-%D8%AF%DA%A9%D8%AA%D8%B1%D8%A7%DB%8C-%D8%AF%D8%A7%D9%86%D8%B4%DA%AF%D8%A7%D9%87-%D8%B9%D9%84%D9%85-%D9%88-%D8%B5%D9%86%D8%B9%D8%AA-%D8%A7%DB%8C%D8%B1%D8%A7%D9%86/)).

This [title](https://scholar.google.com/scholar?hl=en&as_sdt=0%2C5&q=The%20effective%20stability%20parameter%20for%20two-component%20galactic%20discs%3A%20is%20%24Q-%201%E2%89%88%20Q-%201stars%2B%20Q-%201gas%3F&btnG=) comes from google schoolar.

Note that, using `{$Q^{-1}\sim Q^{-1}_{\text{stars}}+Q^{-1}_{\text{gas}}$}?`, the numbers appear in the formula, are in Persian.
Thanx

Comment: What have you tried so far (single `$` not double -- it's inline maths, and [anyway `$$` is a bad idea](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/503/28808))?

Comment: OK, now **what errors**? **What did you try to type it as**?

Comment: Please help us (and also you) and add a minimal working example with bibliography ([MWEB](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4407/how-to-write-a-mweb-minimal-working-example-with-bibliography)), that illustrates your problem. Your code isn't compilable  (at the momenT).

Comment: @Bobyandbob : Sorry for ambiguities. If it helps, I bring the link of thesis sample.

Comment: Change `$Q^{- 1}\sim Q^{- 1}_{stars}+ Q^{- 1}_{gas}?$` to `{$Q^{-1}\sim Q^{-1}_{stars}+Q^{-1}_{gas}$}?` should be fine. Also, if you have loaded `amsmath`, consider `{$Q^{-1}\sim Q^{-1}_{\text{stars}}+Q^{-1}_{\text{gas}}$}?`.

Comment: @RuixiZhang: Thank U so much. It seems to be ok now. However, the numbers in this formula are in Persian :(